# How to make SQL query with Worker Service

Tags: c#, api, firebird, worker

I would like to get the Windows service to connect in a time interval with the database and send the data to the prepared API. For the web service I chose *Worker Services* and tutorial from Tim Corey. The problem is that I didn't find any instructions how to create a connection to the database, create a SQL query and send it to the API.

Database connection added to `Program.cs`

`Program.cs`

```
using Serilog;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

namespace WorkerService
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.Debug()
               .Enrich.FromLogContext()
               .WriteTo.File(@"C:\temp\workservice\LogFile.txt")
               .CreateLogger();

           try
           {
                Log.Information("Starting up the service...");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Log.Fatal(ex, "There was a problem starting the service");
               return;
           }
           finally
           {
               Log.CloseAndFlush();
           } 
        }

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .UseWindowsService()
              .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
              {
                var connection = new FbConnection("database=local:3050/C:/TEST.FDB;user=SYSDBA;password=masterkey");
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
           .UseSerilog();
```

And where or how to add in `worker.cs` SQL query command and send it to URL for example

```
connection.Open();

try
{
    FbCommand cmd = new connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user where ID=1";
    FbDataReader exist = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Connectin error");
    return;
```

and finally `Command.Text` send to API

```
    private const string URL = "https://web.eu/api";
    private const string DATA = Command.Text;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a worker service in .Net ( version 5+) you can go through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service.

the above link is from microsoft docs, they have explained how you can build a worker service (in .NetFramework context, a windows service) using backgroundService.

which is similar to what you have done already, only thing is you need to just add your class worker.cs (right click on project add class).

then you need to extend `worker: BackgroundService`.

then you need to override `ExecuteAsync()` method from BackgroundService class, add in this method you can start adding your logic.

```
services.AddHostedService<Worker>() will call `ExecuteAsync()` when service start up.
```

There are also other methods like, `StopAsync() and StartAsync()` for your service start and stop logics.